# Update Row Number after filtered results TableSorter 2.0

Tags: jquery

So basically i have a numbered row that counts the results.  (similar to the row number in excel) and currently, it'll re-number them after you sort the table, but I can't seem to get it to work after you filter the table.  So if it pulls only records 6-9, the numbers 6-9 are still there, rather than renumbering it to 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Currently, this is what i have:

```
var table = $("#myTable");
table.bind("sortEnd",function() { 
    var i = 1;
    table.find("tr:gt(1)").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(i);
        i++;
    });
}); 
table.bind("filterEnd",function() { 
    var i = 1;
    table.find("tr:gt(1)").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(i);
        i++;
    });
});
```

Using Table:

```
 +===+=======+========+
 | # | Name  | Amount |
 +===+=======+========+
 | 1 | Item1 | 8934   |
 +===+=======+========+
 | 2 | Item2 | 8971   |
 +===+=======+========+
 | 3 | Item3 | 4891   |
 +===+=======+========+
```

If i filter for amount < 5000, it comes out as:

```
 +===+=======+========+
 | # | Name  | Amount |
 +===+=======+========+
 | 3 | Item3 | 4891   |
 +===+=======+========+
```

Where i want that 3 to change to a 1 (being as it's now the first item in the list). Any suggestions?  I've been trying to use filterEnd but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery each:

```
$("table").bind("filterEnd",function() {
    $("#myTable tbody tr:visible").each(function(index){
       $("td:first-child", $(this)).html(index+1);
    });
});
```